# Has any US official said that the economy cannot be "fixed" if the pandemic is not "fixed"?

Tags: united-states, economics, covid-19

### Context

A week ago or so, Romania observed a conflict between the central authorities dealing with the pandemic (who want more restrictions) and the local authorities in a county (who want fewer restrictions). This has escalated to fighting in courts.

### The claim

An argument brought by a Romaniancentral figure was that [the US uses restrictions](https://www.digi24.ro/stiri/actualitate/social/raed-arafat-anunta-ca-va-ataca-decizia-curtii-de-apel-de-a-anula-ordinul-dsu-privind-carantinarea-timisoarei-1474908) to tackle the pandemic because the economy cannot come first:

> He only looks at the economic aspects. They are very important, but there is a saying in the USA: "If you don't sort out the biology, you won't sort out the economy." If you do not solve the problem of biology during the pandemic, the economy will suffer. [Google Translate]

I tried finding a source for this to confirm the claim, but I could not find it (also searched for variations).

Has any US public figure ever expressed this idea (variations also count)?

Comment: An ok question for this site, but if you want a political analysis, you should ask on https://politics.stackexchange.com/. On Skeptics we'll only verify the claim. The claim is a bit vague, but I'm sure there's plenty of Americans to quote expressing this idea.

Comment: @fredsbend I am only interested in the claim, not its political side.

Answer (score 5):

A lot of people have been saying this, but your quote may be referring to when Biden said it in the 2020 presidential debates, as mentioned by [CNBC](https://mobile.twitter.com/cnbc/status/1311119584485879808):

> "You can't fix the economy until you fix the Covid crisis." Joe Biden slams President Trump's economic policies around the coronavirus pandemic.

Similar quotes appear in [Yahoo Finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/amphtml/news/to-fix-the-economy-you-need-to-fix-the-pandemic-former-white-house-economist-202243438.html), [The Washington Post](https://www.washingtonpost.com/outlook/2020/03/30/only-way-reopen-economy-is-stop-spread-coronavirus/), and [Politico](https://www.politico.com/amp/news/agenda/2020/07/10/if-you-want-to-save-the-economy-stop-the-pandemic-355383) but none are from current US officials.